# Automatic username generation from name fields at registration

Tags: forms, hooks

Drupal core 8.6.5

I am trying to change the user registration process to omit the username field and generate the username from the first name and last name.

Since I am new to Drupal and want to learn more I try to go without project modules for that task.

So far I set up a custom module and deactivated the username field. 
Now I should set a default value for it.

How can I set the username built of first name and last name before the process is going on?
And strip some blanks, unallowed characters, ...

I was thinking of hooking into function user_validate_name
Is that possible?

My module so far:

```
<?php
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function my_register_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{   
    $form['account']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['account']['name']['#default_value'] ='tbd'; und 
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting case in Drupal 8. Previously we could look at the user registration form's validation processes, which in Form API were callback strings in the `#validate` property array (or attached to each element in the `#element_validate` property. Note that the Drupal term "element property" means an item in a form array prefixed with a "#".

A basic strategy is similar: alter the form's `#validate` property and *add*, not replace, a string referencing a valid PHP callable. Again, probably best to re-order validate callbacks for first-in, first-out.

```
// Probably best to add this as the first element of #validate
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_register_form_validate';
```

Then implement the function or callable.

```
function my_register_form_validate($form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
  // This should do the trick.
  $formState->setValue('name', $name);
  // But you might need to get the entity from form state storage?
}
```

But we also need to make sure that the user account form doesn't let you change user name, of it does, then add the same validation/form alter.

In Drupal 8, entities often have their properties validated not in the form but as part of [Symfony Constraints](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) as part of their [Typed Data data definition](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/typed-data-api/data-definitions). This is so that Drupal is more API-first rather than form-driven (like in Drupal 7).

So I think you're on the right track to look kind of into `user_validate_name`, but it appears to be unused except in the installer. I think that modifying the entity's base field definition and adding a new constraint would work too.

To do this implement [hook_entity_base_field_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_base_field_info_alter/8.6.x). Also see the following question [How to easily alter an entitys base field definition per bundle?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253257/how-to-easily-alter-an-entitys-base-field-definition-per-bundle?rq=1).

```
function my_register_form_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'user') {
    $fields['name']->getConstraints()
  }
}
```

Then implement a Constraint plugin and its corresponding ConstraintValidator class. The ConstraintValidator class might have a validate method like this:

```
public function validate($items, Constraint $constraint) {
  // The entity should be available on all fields as a parent typed data via FieldItemListInterface::getEntity method
  $entity = $items->getEntity();
  // Generate user name as say $name.
  $items->set($name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your help. Worked great for me.

I have already deactivated the possibility to change the username. If lastname changes (e.g. marriage) I want to keep the username.

```
<?php
use \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
*/
function my_register_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    $form['account']['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
    $form['account']['name']['#default_value'] = 'tbd';
    array_unshift($form['#validate'],'my_register_form_validate');

}

function my_register_form_validate($form, FormStateInterface $formState)
{
    $firstname = $formState->getValue('field_firstname');
    $lastname = $formState->getValue('field_lastname');
    $name = $firstname[0]['value'].$lastname[0]['value'];
    $formState->setValue('name', $name);
}
```