# How can I setRequired() for a BaseFieldDefinition per entity bundle?

Tags: entities, 9

I have an entity type **animal** with the following bundles:

- cow
- pig
- sparrow
- anteater

In the **Animal.php** entity type definition, I create some base fields, one of which is an entity reference to **Habitat**.

```
BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Habitat ID'))
  ->setCardinality(1)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'habitat')
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', FALSE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I want to require this entity reference for cows and pigs, but I don't want it to be required for sparrows and anteaters.

So, I can't use `->setRequired()` in `BaseFieldDefinition::create()` because that will apply to all the bundles.

What's the simplest way to require a field created by `BaseFieldDefinition::create()` in some bundles but not others?

Comment: The simplest way is to store an override in config. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/253257/how-to-easily-alter-an-entitys-base-field-definition-per-bundle

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but I believe you can override [ContentEntityBase::bundleFieldDefinitions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AbundleFieldDefinitions/9.4.x), returning the fields based on the bundle type.